# Unable to searchAndUpdate on BuildFire Datastore

Tags: buildfire

I am trying to run the searchAndUpdate operation on some data that I have saved in the BuildFire Datastore.  The code is as follows:

```
  function updateCategories(category) {
    var filter = {
      "displayPosition": {"$gte": category.displayPosition},
      "name": {"$not": category.name}
    };

    var updateTerms = {
      "$inc": {displayPosition: 1}
    };

    return Datastore.searchAndUpdate(filter, updateTerms, 'category');
  }
```

The Datastore.searchAndUpdate function I am using is just a wrapper that promisifies the original BuildFire version of this method.  The code is as follows:

```
function searchAndUpdate(filter, record, tag) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    Buildfire.datastore.searchAndUpdate(filter, record, tag, function(err, status) {
      if (err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
      } else {
        deferred.resolve(status);
      }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

Whenever I try to run this update function, I always receive a 400 as a response.  This is a screenshot of what I see in the console:

[image]

I have tried this both on my localhost and in the actual Buildfire platform with no luck.  I have also tried building the search criteria both the way shown here (which is the way that is shown in the sdk wiki examples for this method) as well as the way shown in the normal search method (where it uses "$json." prefixes for search properties).  Either way I try it I receive the same response.  I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly, or if there is a problem on BuildFire's end, but I receive no error message, so I'm not sure what is happening.

Comment: I think your filter object may be off. Here is an example {filter: {"$json.name":"Jane Doe"}

Comment: I tried using the filter object the way you showed, but I still receive a 400 response.  {          filter: {
            "$json.displayPosition": {"$gte": category.displayPosition},
            "$json.name": {"$not": category.name}
          }}

Answer (score 2):

the filter is wrong, for not equal search you need to use "$ne" not "$not".
you can check all Search Operators in https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/Search-Operators

Comment: Changing it from $not to $ne fixed the rejection issue, but there is still no incrementation happening on the displayPosition property of the filtered records.  I am assuming the filter works as I have tested it in a plain search and it filtered the records properly.  Any ideas?

Comment: on what side you are running this?
widget or control panel?

Comment: I am running this on the control panel

Comment: @tbergen1, you can try again
fixes has been deployed